# Need to update openssh-server to latest version in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, updates, partial-upgrade

How do I update this version to a later version of openssh-server?
They are up to openssh-8.8p1

On Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Why do you need this? If you want latest security updates, they are backported to the version that is currently in Ubuntu.

Comment: We run a Nessus Advanced Scan and it is requiring us to upgrade to openssh-8.5x or later.

Comment: Then don't stick with 20.04 and prepare an upgrade to 21.04. Or find a source version and install it in /opt/

Comment: Or use a security service that understands how Debian-based systems work.